Node is still running after uninstall
I have a Ubuntu 24.04 virtual machine. I found node was eating all my ram and cpu. I don't need it on my machine but I can't seem to uninstall it.
I ran apt remove nodejs and after that node -v returns Command 'node' not found But If I look in top I still have multiple instances of node running.
I reboot and after a bit node comes back in the process list.
Running whereis node gives me node: so it shouldn't exist anywhere.
It seems to be running in my user account but when I try node -v and whereis node in the user account I get nothing.
   1404 tyson     20   0 1133204  20212   2560 R  10.8   2.1   0:04.88 node                                     
   2115 tyson     20   0 1375668 183164   2688 R  10.8  18.6   0:26.28 node                                     
   1378 tyson     20   0   11.2g  64020   2688 R   5.6   6.5   0:06.92 node 

Am I missing a step?

As another point of information. When I connect to the server using vscode's remote connection the node processes spawn.

Disconnecting with vscode the node process remains.

Did you reboot after removing node? It may be running from RAM

Yep, rebooted. I am thinking it is vscode. When I connect node runs as my user. Digging through the files vscode puts in .vscode it brings node along with itself.
